# Stream Kinect RGB data to web browser using HTML5 and websocket

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, kinect, rgb

I know this topic is not new. I've seen and read some of the articles and resources discussing and even have the demo on how to stream the Kinect data to web browser.

I have an application written in VB.NET and I wanted to ONLY stream the RGB to the web browser. I couldn't find a detailed explanation on how I should modify the codes or how to use the plug-in provided step by step.

I have found the source code for streaming skeleton data to web browser and it's working, but now I want to stream the RGB data. I have seen a lot of website talking about node.js and web socket. But the question is how to use them? anybody please answer~ Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  You want to use the Kinect as a web cam, and the person with the Kinect physically present will have this video data accessible via getUserMedia on a page?  Or, you want to stream live video to many clients over the internet and just happen to want to use Kinect as your video source?  And, why do you want to write the code to do this yourself?

Comment: thanks for the comment~ yes, I am basically trying to stream live video to clients over internet using Kinect as the video source. So, when I start my app, which is starting the streaming, it will send the RGB to the website I hosted. How to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with you using Kinect.  Just install the DirectShow filter (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ee6e7ca-123d-4838-82b6-e5816bf6529c/can-now-use-kinect-camera-with-skype?forum=kinectsdk) and use some streaming software that uses DirectShow for capture.  VLC can do this.  Then, you need a streaming server, and a way to play that back for your clients.  There are hundreds of options... you would have to be much more specific.  This question has also been asked/answered here many times.  How many users are going to be watching?  10?  10 million?

Comment: It is part of my project for monitoring purpose, so there won't be so many users are watching. Maybe yeah, around 10 people. So there is no need to use node.js or refine the coding inside the app? because I've seen them using quite complex coding to display the live streaming RGB data from kinect to the canvas. anyway, Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Sure, if you wanted to put the video right on to the page of the person with the Kinect, that's completely different.  All you're looking for is standard live video streaming.  Nothing more.